# Swiper con Angular, error al cargar mas slides, pierde estilos visuales y no carga el total

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, swiper

Estoy realizando un carrousel de slides con swiper en Angular, funciona todo correctamente hasta que llamo mediante un boton a cargas mas slides dinamicamente, en el momento que trae la respuesta no se ve igual que al principio.

[image: Visual al cargar por primera vez la app]

**Asi se ve al cargar por primera vez la app**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Al darle a este botón se cargas más peliculas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero al cargarlas aparecen de esta manera, ya no se ve igual y no muestra todos los elementos del array**

No entiendo por que pierde los estilos al cargar otra pagina de peliculas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Al principio tengo 10 arrays y al cargar mas carga otros 10 arrays**

Este es el codigo que tengo implementado:

**Componente html**

```
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let pares of peliculas | pares">

    <ion-row>

      <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let pelicula of pares">
        <ion-card>
          <img class="poster" 
               [src]="pelicula.poster_path | imagen">
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </swiper-slide>

  <swiper-slide class="slide-mas">
    <ion-button class="btn-mas" 
                size="large"
                (click)="onClick()">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </swiper-slide>

</swiper-container>
```

**Componente .ts**

```
import { Pelicula } from '../../interfaces/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slideshow-pares',
  templateUrl: './slideshow-pares.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slideshow-pares.component.scss'],
})
export class SlideshowParesComponent  implements OnInit {

  @Input() peliculas: Pelicula[] = [];
  @Output() cargarMas = new EventEmitter();

  slideOpts = {
    slidesPerView: 3.3,
    freeMode: true,
    spaceBetween: -10
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onClick(){
    this.cargarMas.emit();
  }

}
```

Lo unico que hago con el output es enviar el evento al componente padre para que haga la llamada nuevamente al servicio y lo agregue al arrego que ya existia de esta forma:

```
    this.moviesService.getPopulares()
      .subscribe( resp => {

        const arrTemp = [ ...this.populares, ...resp.results ];
        this.populares = arrTemp;
      })
  }
```

Alguna forma de que no se me pierda el estilo de vista?

Estoy trabajando con Ionic 7+, Angular 17+